# How to rotate an element in several steps, starting from last position?

Tags: svg, rotation, svg-animate

I have the following SVG document :
https://jsfiddle.net/724vgh5z/

I would like the blue rectangle to rotate by 6 degrees every time the red rectangle has completed a full circle.

It almost works, but the blue rectangle always start back at 0 degrees.
I would like the blue rectangle to perform rotations like this : `0 -> 6, 6-> 12, 12 -> 18, ...`
I can't hardcode all rotations since there will be lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question:

Add another animation transform inside a `<g>` container:

[https://jsfiddle.net/82fxqc6e/](https://jsfiddle.net/g49s3rk2/)

```
<svg width="200" height="200">    
    <g transform="translate(100 100)">
      <g>
        <animateTransform type="rotate" values="45" begin="2.5s" 
         calcMode="discrete" dur="2.5s" additive="sum" accumulate="sum"
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <rect .../>
      </g>
      ...
    </g>    
</svg>
```

The trick is to use `calcMode="discrete"` and `values="...`" attributes.